# Array Slicing for recursive function in Java

Tags: java, recursion, memory-management

I was working on a Java implementation of constructing a binary tree, given the pre/inorder traversal arrays.

Code looks something like this (seems to work but I havent tested extensively)

```
   public static TreeNode buildTree(int[] inOrder, int[] preOrder) {
    if(inOrder.length <= 0 || preOrder.length <= 0) {
        return null;
    }
    final TreeNode root = new TreeNode(preOrder[0]);
    final int i = indexOf(inOrder, root.getValue());
    root.setLeft(buildTree(Arrays.copyOfRange(inOrder, 0, i),
                           Arrays.copyOfRange(preOrder, 1, i + 1)));
    root.setRight(buildTree(Arrays.copyOfRange(inOrder, i + 1, inOrder.length), 
                            Arrays.copyOfRange(preOrder, i + 1, preOrder.length)));
    return root;
}
```

However that got me thinking about what the best practices are for array slicing in java. Since copyOfRange() returns a new array, is this solution very memory inefficient?

Or is the JavaVM smart enough to reuse memory when all these similar subarrays are being created.

(I know I could rewrite this function with start/end indices in the function signature. My question is more along the line, of whether it would ever be okay to do array slicing like this in Java)

Comment: I doubt that the memory will be reused. Indexes into the array would be a lot better.

Comment: Try switching over to `List`s. You can `sublist` a `List` much more efficiently.

Comment: How should reusing memory work here?

Comment: Why is sublist() more efficient does it modify the list in memory or does it create a new List object. Seems to be unclear from the doccumentation